# Split string on separator with deep nested brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like following:

```
"a|b|c(d|e(f|g))|h|"
```

I need to split it by separator | but ignoring the separator in within brackets

The expected result is a String array

```
["a", "b", "c(d|e(f|g))", "h", ""]
```

My code:

```
public static String[] splitter(String input, char separator) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int level = 0;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c == '|' && level == 0) {
            result.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append(c);
            if (c == '(') level++;
            else if (c == ')' && level > 0) level--;
        }
    }
    result.add(stringBuilder.toString());
    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

The code works as expected but I wonder if there is some better solution, preferably using regexp.

Comment: Regex is not correct tool for this job (at least regex engine used in Java which doesn't support recursion). Writing your own method seems like correct solution.

Comment: You should ponder over what you consider "better", and why a regex would be. If such a solution was possible (it isn't in Java, although it is in perl) it would likely be shorter, but that's about the only advantage I can see. On the other hand, I guarantee it would be both less performant and much less maintainable, so you'd be wasting CPU cycles and developper's time to save little disk space

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote my code from scratch minutes ago. I have just reinvented the wheel :-)